# Ionic how to match a word in array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a policy_id in my app and the list of array where multiple policy_no are in array . I need to show data of policy_no from array which i have. 
[image]

[image]
I attach the image i need to match the policy_id with plicy_no in array and show only that array result .

```
      this.policy_id = this.navParams.get('y'); // here is policy id
      console.log(this.policy_id);
      this.policies = this.navParams.get('z'); // here the policies array 
      console.log(this.policies);
```

Comment: i add the data images in picture one there is policy_no i want only data of that policy_id as shown in second image

Comment: loop through both the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getRelatedPolicies(policy_id, policies) {
    return policies.filter(policy => policy.policy_no === policy_id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply . but i have a policy_id (its not come from array. its string ) also updated my code . so i want to match the policy_id to policies array in which policy_no is in array.

Comment: Modified my answer, check now

Comment: So you modified your code to be identical to the code I posted three hours ago?

Comment: @RemiSture Are you talking about MDN's filter function? Are you blaming me for that? And just because of this you downvoted my answer? Instead of just thinking about gaining numerical reputations, try to understand why my answer has been accepted though you have posted something similar before me. It's all about the specific solution for a given problem. Hope you will understand :)

Comment: My reaction is based on that your original answer was about 95% different than your current answer (which again oddly enough is pretty much identical to a couple of the other answers here :))

Answer (score 1):

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The find() method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

```
 const police_id="abc";
 let res = policies.find(x => x.policy_no === police_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your array like this:

```
const policy_id = 'xxx';
const policies = [{ policy_no: 'xxx'}, { policy_no: 'yyy'}]
console.log(policies.filter((p) => p.policy_no === policy_id));
```

Comment: when i console yourPolicy its showing me blank array . also updated my code in question how ill get the policy_id and policies array . Thanks

Comment: Updated my example.

Comment: in console its just showing the policy_no . not the data with policy_no. I add code like this                                                                                                              
    const policy_id = this.policy_id; 
    const policies = [{ policy_no: this.policy_id}] 
    console.log(policies.filter((policies) => policies.policy_no === policy_id));

Comment: `policies` is supposed to be your `policies` array. My code is just a sample code to illustrate what you need to do. It would of course be much easier to help you if you posted code instead of images of code.